# How does one access a super's view controller?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a problem and I will try to explain the issue:

1. I have one main `UIViewController` (Whole screen)
2. I have one secondary `UIViewController` (setbounds)
3. I added my secondary view to my `mainView` using this:

   ```
   [mainController.view addSubview:secondaryController.view];
   ```
4. I created a third controller: `modalController`, I added it to my secondary controller like this:

   ```
   [secondaryController presentModalViewController:modalController animated:YES];
   ```
5. I make calculus based on some events inside of my `modelController`.
6. I am able to send messages from my `modalController` to my `secondaryController` using:

   ```
   [[self parentViewController]  performSelector : @selector(myMethodInSecondaryController:) withObject : myObject afterDelay : .5];
   ```

   **NOTE:** "self" corresponds to the `modalController`
7. I need to pass "myObject" to my `mainController`, but i cant make reference to my `mainController` from the `secondaryController`. I tried this:

   ```
   [[self parentViewController] performSelector : @selector(myMethodInMainController:) withObject:myObject afterDelay : .5];
   ```

   **NOTE:** "self" corresponds to the `secondaryController`

   but it doesn't work, i have access to my mainController's view using : `self.view.superview`

   **NOTE:** "self" is my `secondaryController`

but no to its controller.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In your secondary controller, try

```
id mainViewController = [self.view.superview nextResponder];
```

and check if this is the view controller you're looking for.

Apple's documentation of `-[UIResponder nextResponder]`:

> UIView implements this method by returning the UIViewController object that manages it (if it has one) or its superview (if it doesn’t)

Comment: Thanks Nikolai !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
That worked perfectly :)

thanks 
Regards from Guadalajara Mexico!!
Alejandra :)